# Redirect input from file AND show the input

Tags: linux, redirect, input, io

Is there a way to take standard input from a file and show that input in the console when the program runs?

For example:

```
std::string s;
std::cout << "Input: ";
std::cin >> s;
std::cout << "Output: " << s << std::endl;
```

infile.txt:

```
apple
```

./program < infile.txt shows:

```
Input: Output: apple
```

But I'd like it to show:

```
Input: apple
Output: apple
```

Comment: Could you give an example? After reading about it, I don't see how it could output the redirected input in addition to the standard output.

Comment: I understand what do you mean: you want to put into stdout everything just readed from stdin. `tee` can't do that. Change your own code.